# bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: bash, ubuntu, su, source, lfs

Trying to execute the source command  using "lfs" user on ubuntu 14.04 and getting this:

```
root@linux:~/lfs# su lfs - -c "source ~/.bash_profile"
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Any ideas?

Background info: I am following the LFS book, making a script out of it, so in my script which I execute with sudo, when it gets to this part, after creating the lfs user and his .bashrc and .bashprofile, I guess it is loading it.

## Context:

```
echo "info: create 'lfs' group and user..."
groupadd -f lfs
id -u lfs &>/dev/null || useradd -s /bin/bash -g lfs -m -k /dev/null lfs
passwd -d -q lfs

echo "info: make 'lfs' own the 'tools' and 'sources' directories..."
chown lfs $LFS/tools
chown lfs $LFS/sources

echo "info: creating a clean '.bash_profile' as user 'lfs'..."
su lfs - -c "cat > ~/.bash_profile << \"EOF\"
exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
EOF"

echo "info: creating a clean '.bashrc' as user 'lfs'..."
su lfs - -c "cat > ~/.bashrc << \"EOF\"
set +h
umask 022
LFS=/mnt/lfs
LC_ALL=POSIX
LFS_TGT=$(uname -m)-lfs-linux-gnu
PATH=/tools/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
export LFS LC_ALL LFS_TGT PATH
EOF"

su lfs - -c "source ~/.bash_profile"
```

## Edit:

It has been suggested that my syntax is incorrect, I am not at my linux machine at the moment, so will try to use different syntax when I get the chance. However, for info, I got the syntax from the answer here:  https://serverfault.com/questions/411307/cannot-set-terminal-process-group-during-su-to-another-user-as-login-shell

Comment: Do you want `su` to run bash as if it were a login shell? If so, then try `su - lfs -c ...` or `su --login lfs -c ...` or `su lfs --login -c ...`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That gives the same error.

Answer (score 10):

- `su - username` runs the login shell of `username` as an interactive shell.
- `su username command arguments` runs `command arguments` *non-interactively* under the account `username`.

You command `su lfs - -c "source ~/.bash_profile"` means run `- -c "source ~/.bash_profile"` as the user `lfs` *non-interactively*. Now the shell sees the option `-` and says, I am to run as an interative login shell, and tries to initialize the terminal, but `su` has disconnected the child process from the controlling terminal.

In short: The `-` is either misplaced or erroneous.

For a longer discussion, see practically the [the same question](https://serverfault.com/questions/411307/cannot-set-terminal-process-group-during-su-to-another-user-as-login-shell) on serverfault.

Comment: What do you mean by “run … non-interactively”? And by “`su` has disconnected the child process from the controlling terminal”? Either you're using the wrong terminology (but I can't figure out what you're intended) or you're confused as to what is going on.

Comment: Summary: the correct syntax is either `su username command arguments`, `su username`, or `su - username`. The form used by the original poster, `su username - command arguments` is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks for your reply. Why do you think the previous lines in the script work? They use the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when switching user inside the docker container. I fixed it by adding **--pty (-P)** option that creates a pseudo terminal for the session and avoids TIOCSTI ioctl terminal injection. So the following command should fix the issue:

```
su lfs -l -P -c ...
```